# Menu control in Child master page cannot be accessed in content page in nested master page scenario

Tags: .net, asp.net

I have a nested master page scenario where I have a menu both in main master and in the child master page. Now if I try to access either of the two... both are not accessible in the content page. I am using this code to access it. The variable n is getting null value.

```
Menu n = (Menu)this.Master.FindControl("Menu1");
```

Comment: Why do you want to access a control in the Master page from the content page? Sounds like a design problem.

Comment: The child master page is having a menu... whenever the link in the menu is clicked i have to make it selected one... this can be done only in coding at the child content page

Comment: your are right ! If we have only one master page the code is working but in the case of nested master page it is not !

Comment: (1) whatever you want to write in content page's coding, you can write the same thing to menu's databind event as well.
(2) If you do really need to access the master page in your scenerio, you can try like :
(Menu)this.Master.Master.FindControl("Menu1")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your Menu control at the root level in this.Master?  FindControl isn't recursive, so if your Menu is nested inside of another control (a Panel, etc.) then FindControl will return null.

You can write your own recursive version of FindControl, which is what I did on a previous project.  This is off the top of my head (I don't have the code in front of me):

```
public static Control RecursiveFindControl(ControlCollection cc, String id) {
    Control c = cc.FindControl(id);

    if (c == null) {
        foreach (Control child in cc) {
            if (child.HasChildren) {
                return RecursiveFindControl(child.Controls, id);
            }
        }
    }

    return c;
}
```

Call it this way:

```
Menu foo = (Menu)RecursiveFindControl(this.Master.Controls, "menu");
```